# How to define a symbol which combines = and one similar to <?

Tags: symbols

How to define a symbol in the following picture which combines = and one similar to <?

[image]

Note that it's not < in the picture and the left side of the symbol has some radian.

*Remark.* It's an old symbol (Schröder, 1890, *Vorlesungen über die Algebra der Logik (Exakte Logik)*, Leipzig: B.G. Teubner. p.132) for implication for which we usually use → instead and some people may use ⊃ or ⇒ instead.

Comment: 'it looks like the first instance of the symbol is not the same as the second.  Is that an artifact of the scan, or are they really different?  Also, what is the origin of this symbol?

Comment: "Yes"?  But my comment contains three questions.  To which one is "yes" the answer?  It's either 1 *or* 2, and 3 asks for explicit information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The second line is probably bad printing, the last line contains the intended symbol. About the origin: Ernst Schröder invented this symbol. He didn't like the one invented by C.S. Peirce who used a dash and at its right end a less-than symbol.

Comment: @UdoWermuth -- Thanks.  Is it in current/general use?  If so, and there's a good published instance available, it can be submitted as a Unicode request.

Comment: @barbarabeeton For the 1st question, Yes; for the 2nd one, No; and for the 3rd one, see the remark which has been revised. Furthermore, right now we don't use it any more   which is just a historical symbol.

Comment: @M.Logic -- Historical symbols, if the works are still referenced, do get added to Unicode with sufficiently solid documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @egreg (see [the solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691722/140814)), I give two solutions. Clearly the first one is more close to Schröder's, and is my taste. Some articles or books also use the symbol which is similar to but less beautiful than the second one. Both the first and second ones are OK. You can choose any one as you like.

**1. Combine a part of `\circ`, a part of `<` and `=`.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@schroder
\newcommand{\roundless}{\mathrel{\@schroderfalse\mathpalette\round@less\relax}}
\newcommand{\round@less}[2]{%
  \clipbox{0pt 0pt {0.755\width} 0pt}{\raisebox{0.145ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.745]{$\m@th#1\circ$}}}%
  \clipbox{{0.38\noexpand\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\m@th#1<$}%
  \if@schroder\settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1<$}\kern-0.05\dimen@\fi
}
\newcommand{\schroderimply}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\schroder@imply\relax}}%%Shroder imply
\newcommand{\schroder@imply}[2]{%
  \vphantom{<}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\@schrodertrue\round@less{#1}{}$\cr$\m@th#1=$\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\schroderconimply}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{\ensuremath\schroderimply}}}%%Shroder converse  imply
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\huge
 \[\phi\schroderimply \psi\schroderconimply \theta\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2. Combine a part of `\subset` and `=`.** The solution also benefits more or less from the solution @Davislor as above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@schroder
\newcommand{\varsubset}{\mathrel{\@schroderfalse\mathpalette\var@subset\relax}}
\newcommand{\var@subset}[2]{%
    \clipbox{0pt 0pt {0.525\width} 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
    \clipbox{{0.725\noexpand\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
    \if@schroder\settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1\subset$}\kern-0.05\dimen@\fi
}
\newcommand{\schroderimply}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\schroder@imply\relax}}%Shroder imply
\newcommand{\schroder@imply}[2]{%
    \vphantom{\subset}%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$\@schrodertrue\var@subset{#1}{}$\cr$\m@th#1=$\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\schroderconimply}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{\ensuremath\schroderimply}}}%Shroder converse  imply
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\huge
 \[\phi\schroderimply \psi\schroderconimply \theta\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hope them useful for your Unicode submit application.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a command with the first symbol, then `\hspace{-1em}` and then the next symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\smequal{<\hspace{-1em}=}

\begin{document}
    $a \smequal b$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

After your edit to specify it should not be `<`, you could also use tikz:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\smequal{\ \tikz{\draw (0.5em,0.5em) to[out=-180,in=70] (0,.25em) to[out=-70,in=-180] (0.5em, 0);}\hspace{-1em}=}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    $a \smequal b$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you did not specify what the "similar to <" should look like you need to tweak the parameters until you are happy...

EDIT:

Of course one can also remove the whitespaces around the symbol:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\smequal{\tikz{\draw (0.5em,0.5em) to[out=-180,in=70] (0,.25em) to[out=-70,in=-180] (0.5em, 0);}\hspace{-1em}=\hspace{-0.3em}}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    $a \smequal b$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

For me that would be too tight... but of course you can also tweak the parameters to suit to your whitespacing needs.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have now also added this new request to my answer.

Comment: The spaces before and after the symbol in the second solution are not suitable. It's a relation symbol and so he spaces before and after it should have the same space as the other relation symbols.

Comment: In the second solution it has normal spaces around the symbol... I now give up as you keep coming up with new requirements. Also I have mentioned that you can adapt the solution 3 to your exact and changing requirements for spacing...

Answer (score 5):

I am unfamiliar with this symbol, but it certainly seems to be font-dependent. You can use `\ooalign` to superimpose a `=` symbol with `\smallfrown` (uses `amssymb`) that has been rotated 90 degrees (requires `graphicx`). Using `\mathpalette` the symbol will adjust to script and scriptscript styles.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oldimplies}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\old@implies\relax}}
\newcommand{\old@implies}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1=$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\smallfrown$}$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$A\oldimplies B_{A\oldimplies B_{A\oldimplies B}}$

\end{document}
```

If you'd like to shift the frown to the right a bit you can add some horizontal space, for example `4mu` (which actually only shifts `2mu` since it is centered with the frown).

```
\hidewidth$\m@th#1\mkern4mu\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\smallfrown$}$\hidewidth\cr
```

[image]

Comment: How to control the horizontal position of the rotated small frown?

Comment: @M.Logic: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly similar to ⋹, `\isinE` in `stix` or `unicode-math`. However, the struck-through symbol there is subset.