# How to make the symbol acts well in all font sizes?

Tags: symbols

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\newlength{\weq}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varsubset}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\var@subset\relax}}
\newcommand{\var@subset}[2]{\settowidth{\weq}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
    \clipbox{0pt 0pt {0.525\weq} 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
    \clipbox{{0.725\weq} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
}
\newcommand{\schroderimply}{\mathop{=}\kern-0.725em\mathop{\varsubset}}%Shroder imply
\makeatother


\begin{document}
normal size: {\normalsize $x\schroderimply y$}

footnote size: {\footnotesize $x\schroderimply y$

huge size: {\huge $x\schroderimply y$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the symbol acts well in the normal size and footnote size while wrong in the huge size. So is there any way to improve the codes to make the symbol act well in all sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to right align `\varsubset` with `=`, which can be done by removing the sidebearing to the right. However, this wouldn't be good if you use `\varsubset` by itself, so I introduce a conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@schroder
\newcommand{\varsubset}{\mathrel{\@schroderfalse\mathpalette\var@subset\relax}}
\newcommand{\var@subset}[2]{%
  \clipbox{0pt 0pt {0.525\width} 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
  \clipbox{{0.725\noexpand\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
  \if@schroder\settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1\subset$}\kern-0.05\dimen@\fi
}
\newcommand{\schroderimply}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\schroder@imply\relax}}
\newcommand{\schroder@imply}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\subset}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\@schrodertrue\var@subset{#1}{}$\cr$\m@th#1=$\cr}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
normal size: {\normalsize $x\schroderimply y_{\schroderimply}$}

footnote size: {\footnotesize $x\schroderimply y_{\schroderimply}$}

huge size: {\huge $x\schroderimply y_{\schroderimply}$}

{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\schroderimply$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]